# send data to another controller with $emit

Tags: html, css, angularjs

In my angular app, I have multiple `controllers` and I need to send data from one to another `controller`, So I'm using `$scope.$emit` to transfer data, but unfortunately it's not working.

```js
var app = angular.module('tApp', []);
app.controller('masterpage', function($scope) {
  $scope.masterpagescope = 'A';
});
app.controller('subpage', function($scope) {
  $scope.subpagescope = ['data1', 'data2', 'data2+n'];

  $scope.sendData = function() {
    $scope.$emit('send-data', $scope.masterpagescope,   $scope.subpagescope);
    console.log($scope.masterpagescope);
  }
  $scope.sendData();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="tApp">
  <div ng-controller="masterpage" id="masterpage">
    {{masterpagescope}}
    <div ng-controller="subpage" id="subpage">
    {{subpagescope}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In above snippet I'm trying to send `$scope.subpagescope`'s data to `$scope.masterpagescope`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen to the $emit in the masterpage controller by using $on

```
app.controller('masterpage', function($scope) {
  $scope.masterpagescope = 'A';

  $scope.$on('send-data', function(event, data) { 
    $scope.masterpagescope = data; 
    });
});

app.controller('subpage', function($scope) {
  $scope.subpagescope = ['data1', 'data2', 'data2+n'];

  $scope.sendData = function() {
    $scope.$emit('send-data', $scope.subpagescope);
  }
  $scope.sendData();
});
```

Recommend [this](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/) article on the subject

Comment: Alright! I was trying with incomplete knowledge, :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't subscribed to event in parent controller.

```
$scope.$on('send-data', function(event, data){
//do whatever with data here...
});
```

Also, while emitting, enclose all data in one object:

```
 $scope.$emit('send-data', {master: $scope.masterpagescope,   sub : $scope.subpagescope});
```

PS: Store the value returned by $on, which is deregistration function for subscription of event. Call the stored function on 'destroy' of page.

Comment: jsfiddle of your code with console logging (as it was just what i was about to post) :) https://jsfiddle.net/6x5rpbtr/

Answer (score 1):

You should have `$scope.$on` as the other answers propose.

```
$scope.$on('send-data', function() { ... })
```

But I strongly suggest **not** using `$emit`/`$broadcast` to share data between controllers. A common Angular service will do better.

---

**UPDATE:** Why I don't suggest using `$emit`/`$broadcast`?

1. Usage of `$emit`/`$broadcast` somehow complicated for the beginners.
   You can `$emit` upwards in the Angular scope tree and `$broadcast` downwards. If you need to communicate with a same-level (sibling) scope, then you will need to `$emit` and then `$broadcast` in a parent scope [or use `$rootScope`? -- watch for God object anti-pattern].
2. Every `$scope.$on` will register an event listener. Using it much may cause memory leaks. Of course you can kill event listeners correspondingly (additional work to do).
3. The code may become some degree of mess if there are too many `$emit`/`$broadcast`/`$scope.$on`s around.

Comment: Why do you strongly suggest not using it? Isn't Angularjs services singeltons which make it unfitting in situations where you have multiple master-sub controllers loaded at the same time. Then they will share data between all scopes even if they aren't connected. IMO in that case the pattern will fit fine

Comment: Please see my update Marcus. A small service designed to be used to provide data sharing in a well defined "scope" won't be a problem.

Comment: Nice update! The event listeners will be destroyed when the controller gets destroyed so it wont be a memory leak, I think its default by angular > 1.5. But you are correct, It can get a real mess if you dont keep the controllers small.